# Laravel - group posts by months (eager loading)

Tags: php, laravel, group-by, eager-loading

I would like to list my posts grouped by months

This is my Category Model

```
class Category extends \Eloquent {
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Post', 'category_post_tag')
                    ->select(DB::raw('MONTH(posts.eventStartDate) month, MONTHNAME(posts.created_at) month_name'))
                    ->distinct()
                    ->orderBy('eventStartDate', 'asc');
    }
}
```

So when i do this in my view file:

```
@foreach($category->posts as $index => $post)
    <pre>{{ $post }}</pre>
@endforeach
```

I get this result:

```
{"month":"7","month_name":"July","id":"20","slug":"sunt-et-ipsum-dolorum","title":"Sint dolorum exercitationem."}
{"month":"7","month_name":"July","id":"15","slug":"qui-exercitationem-autem","title":"Id tenetur rem cumque ut."}
{"month":"8","month_name":"July","id":"6","slug":"aspernatur-qui-repellat","title":"Recusandae accusamus omnis dicta."}
{"month":"9","month_name":"July","id":"25","slug":"et-aut-eos-quaerat-soluta-perspiciatis","title":"Facere ullam sint et."}
{"month":"10","month_name":"July","id":"26","slug":"sunt-nemo-aperiam","title":"Voluptatibus harum sunt et ducimus."}
```

Which is ok, because i only have 5 posts, but i would like somehow to group the posts which are in the same month so i can list them out in my view grouped by months

I tried to add groupBy('month') to my posts method (relation) in my Category model but that only makes things worse, because then i only get back one post / month

So i tried this in my view file:

```
@foreach($category->posts as $index => $post)
    {{ $new_array[$post->month][$post->id] = $post }}
@endforeach
```

to create a new array grouped by the months, but this freezes my browser, it just keeps loading and in the end dies with a white screen.

Could someone please point me in the right direction, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupBy` on the collection, not the query:

```
$category->posts->groupBy('month');
```

Comment: Thats not working, it just keeps loading and loading, nothing happens

Comment: Only 5, but i solved it in a different way, im going to post the answer tomorrow, to tired tonight. Thanks anyway @Josep

Comment: @Mr.Sam Didn't you want to post your answer?

Comment: @Mr.Sam didn't you want to post the answer?

Comment: @Mr.Sam Didn't you want to post an answer?